# Check any data after confirmation message using JSON

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, confirmation

I want to make the data alert successfully saved or fail after the user selects on the confirmation message. In this case data checking occurs after the user confirms the message I made.

This is my Javascript Code :

```
$('#add-btn').on('click', function(event){
  var confirmation = confirm("Do you want to save ?");
  if (confirmation == true) {
    var code = $('#code').val();
    var name = $('#name').val();
    var unit = $('#unit').val();
    var price_code = $('#price_code').val();
    var type = $('#type').val();
    var final = $('#final').val();
    var dataString = 'code=' +code+ '&unit=' +unit+ '&price_code=' +price_code+ '&type=' +type;
    if (code != '' && name != '' && unit != '' && price_code != '' && type != '' && final != ''){
      event.preventDefault();
      $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "../public/process/add_data.php",
        data: dataString,
        dataType: "json",
        cache: false,
        success: function(data){
          if(data.status == 'success'){
            alert("Success !");
          }
          else if(data.status == 'error'){
            alert("Data already used !");
          }
        }
      });
    }
    else{
      alert('Please fill all fields !');
    }
  }
});
```

All input success to save but the alert cannot show.

Comment: Have you opened your browser network tools to see if the AJAX request was indeed successful?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally I find my solution. I'm sorry for my carelessness.
That happened because my variable dataString did not complete.
It should be :

```
var dataString = 'code=' +code+ '&name=' +name+ '&unit=' +unit+
'&price_code=' +price_code+ '&type=' +type+ '&final=' +final;
```

Thank you all for your kindness :-)

Answer (score 0):

I think problem in your php file. your JOSN data is not in correct format that you received in success.Please try this in your add_data.php file

```
//All code goes here and after insert try this

$array = array();

if(if data insert successfully) { 
  $array['status '] = 'success';
} else {
  $array['status '] = 'error'; 
}

header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($array);
```

Comment: Hi dipok, thank you for the answer but I already did that on my add_data.php

Answer (score 0):

The success function is only executed if everything went well. If there has been any error, you need to add the Ajax failure function as follows:

```
     $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "../public/process/add_data.php",
        data: dataString,
        dataType: "json",
        cache: false,
        success: function(data){
            alert("Success !");
        }
    }).fail(function () {
            alert("Data already used !");
    });
```

Comment: Hi Iñigo, I already tried that but it did not work too :'( Do you have any other solution? Thank you